# change django upload folder based on queryset

Tags: python, django

Gday, I'm working on a section of my data management project where users will be able to upload premade data for it to be parsed and inputted into the database. I am currently stuck on uploading files. The upload field will be on the main page for the specific dataset, which is navigated to by using the dataset id. What I would like is for any files uploaded in on that page to be saved in a directory such as "/projectroot/uploads/dataset_name". is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```py
def my_memory_file_name(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['my_memory', instance.user.username, filename])


class MyMemory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    situation = models.TextField(help_text="Explain the situation of screenshot in few words")
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text="Date is not a required field")
    screenshot = models.FileField(upload_to=my_memory_file_name)
```